# Is Apache DBCP2 JCA compliant?

Tags: java, jta, jca

I'm working on re-configuring a JEE application to work standalone, and we're making a list of components to use. Two of those are **Narayana** (JTA/transaction manager), and Apache **DBCP2** (JDBC connection pool). It looks like these pieces should work together, but we want to be standards compliant where we can.

So, a question has come up: is DBCP2 a JCA (JEE Connector Architecture) implementation?

JCA compliance might not matter much if we can easily configure DBCP to work with Narayana, so any hints on that front would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late for original purpose but good for future reference: if by JCA compliant you mean JTA managed, then it depends on what DataSource you are gonna use. According to [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/managed/BasicManagedDataSource.html) the `BasicManagedDataSource` is indeed JTA compliant.

Comment: DBCP is not JCA compliant at all, because it doesn't implement any interfaces (`javax.resource` and sub-packages) from JCA.

Comment: JCA not but JTA yes. And I believe thats actually the question, if DBCP is JTA compatible, its formulated wrong.